# Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to in Django?

Tags: django

I am running Debian 6 stable and I am trying to run Django locally using `./manage.py runserver` command. This is what I get:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'genelaytics.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

I tried creating a new django project, still get the same error. What's the problem? I just fresh re-installed Debian yesterday because of this problem. This problem hasn't gone away. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is public ip trouble, just try to use python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.

Comment: Already tried that. I have tried all the possible solutions. None of them worked.

Comment: Done more than 100 times. No luck!

Comment: What is in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: look at this posts http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg92391.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing two lines of code in network configuration file. Edit the file as a root user with any text editor:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add these two lines:

```
    auto lo

    iface lo inet loopback
```

Restart the network using the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Now, the localserver will work fine.

Comment: already this 2 lines are there but still  I am getting error.
 What to do?

Comment: Mohini: check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841295/error-that-ip-address-cant-be-assigned-to-when-running-app

Answer (score 8):

That's not related to Django but to your network configuraton. The very basic `loopback interface` is not working properly. If you want to [learn more about networking and this layer](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node66.html).

Your problem is that your host cannot ping to itself, and so Django gets an error when getting the network address. That's in `django/core/management/commands/runserver.py` and is returned when it gets the system error 99 (`EADDRNOTAVAIL`).

Your network configuration at `/etc/network/interfaces` should have this piece at the beginning:

```
# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Check [Debian documentation](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) for full network configuration.

Comment: In my case, this happens on WiFi only, but not when the computer is hooked to a wired Ethernet.  At those points I can use "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" and it all works out ok.

Comment: Already this 2 lines are there but still I am getting error. What to do?