# "Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to" when running app

Tags: python, django

Whenever I'm trying to launch a Django server app with a LAN ip I receive the error:

```
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'servidorMain.settings'
Development server is running at http://192.168.1.XX:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

In localhost it works perfectly. I also was checking the network configuration and I think all is correct so I dont see where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have some other system/user process listening on that port?  What operating system are you running under?

Comment: No, I also was trying with other ports

Comment: have you looked at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505540/error-that-ip-address-cant-be-assigned-to-in-django>?

Comment: Yes I have already seen it, that is in localhost where works perfectly

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is in localhost and my app has also access from mobile devices, by this reason I can't use localhost. The problem is just with the LAN ips

Comment: This is the best solution, don't know why the hell the one above this has a green check mark...

Comment: not worked in my case,python manage.py runserver 0:8000 it running successfully but in browser I got error "Unable to connect" what to do?

Comment: god bless you kind person

Comment: if you face this issue in EC2, try private IP. Thank me later

Comment: Please explain, why it works? @Vladislav Mitov

Say my local IP address it 10.0.0.X
My machine IP is 10.0.0.45

What is the difference between running 0:8000, to running 10.0.0.100: 8000?

Comment: @cegprakash I have tried using the private IP while starting the django server. And also added in the allowed host configurattion of settings.py file. But when I hit server in browser http://privateip:8000/ i get site not reached error. I am facing with EC2 instance.

Comment: check your inbound and outbound rules

Comment: @JavierRR : did you able to solve this problem? the solution given here ,0.8000' is for localhost. for to access the API from the mobile device. how to run all of them on one ip?

Answer (score 6):

You should **check with your IP**, as mine was changed and was getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent to error code #99 in c language errors list, It's described by this term:

> Cannot assign requested address

It is not a permission problem, because permission's error code is different so I think it's because you have not that IP address set on your computer. When you try to run server on an specified IP address, you should have it set on one of your network interfaces.

Simply the IP address you're trying to run server on it is not your current IP address.

Comment: I have for example in this computer 192.168.1.12, which does not work neither.I have created a new ehtX interface but is not the solution.

Comment: Was running my server on a Docker container, and realized this was the issue. Can only use the IP address actually tied to the Docker container, even if there's passthrough from my host.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Amazon EC2 or Lightsail use private and public IPs like this:

Public for browser: `<your-public-ip>:8000`

Private for command line: `python manage.py runserver <your-PRIVATE-ip>:8000`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.
For anyone wondering how to get private IP on AWS Lightsail: Go to main Lightsail page (lightsail.aws.amazon.com), under main 'Instances' tab click your instance. Privare IP will be in the top right corner. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1. run ipconfig in your cmd and copy ipv4 address.
2. go to settings file of the project and the IP as a string in allowed host.
3. now run server using command `python manage.py runserver 0:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Check your Network IP address in CMD or Terminal using `ipconfig` for windows and `ifconfig` for linux
and change IP accordingly for allowed hosts in Settings.py

**Note:** Your IP address may be changed due to service provider added more subnets to it so you just have to replace old by new IP

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'localhost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py. Then, python manage.py runserver localhost:8000. Run localhost:8000 in your url and it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error.

I install Django tenant and its schema module by the below command. And error resolved.

1. `pip install django-tenants`
2. `pip install django-tenant-schemas`

*NOTE:- it could be pip3 in your system*